# Easiest way to mask characters in HTML(5) text input

Tags: javascript, html, masking

Does HTML5 have any kind of text field masking or do I still have to trap `onkeydown` etc.?

jbabey is right--"masking" as in blocking certain illegal characters, not hiding what's typed.

The best (as in simplest and most reliable) way I've found is to trap `onkeyup` and then just run a regex replace on the value of the textfield, removing any illegal characters.

This has a few advantages:

1. It's easy to implement (one function, two lines of code).
2. It's reliable and covers all cases I've thought of.
3. It doesn't block key commands like copy/paste, select all or arrow keys.

But its major disadvantage is it shows the typed character(s) briefly before removing them, which makes it look very hackish and unprofessional.

Comment: Why don't `input` of `type="password"` ?

Comment: Question probably means allowing only certain characters to appear in the text field, for example, numbers and (-) for telephone inputs

Comment: i think he means [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_mask), not [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask)

Comment: Still have to do onkeydown (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728261/how-to-prevent-number-input-on-keydown) unless you want reg-ex style filtering like discussed below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look up the new [HTML5 Input Types](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/).  These instruct browsers to perform client-side filtering of data, but the implementation is incomplete across different browsers.  The `pattern` attribute will do regex-style filtering, but, again, browsers don't fully (or at all) support it.

However, these won't block the input itself, it will simply prevent submitting the form with the invalid data.  You'll still need to trap the `onkeydown` event to block key input before it displays on the screen.

Comment: To improve answer, should give an example of trapping onkeydown.

Answer (score 9):

1. Basic validation can be performed by choosing the **type attribute** of input elements. For example:
   `<input type="email" /> 
    <input type="URL" />
    <input type="number" />`
2. using **pattern** attribute like:
    `<input type="text" pattern="[1-4]{5}" />`
3. **required** attribute
    `<input type="text" required />`
4. **maxlength**:
   `<input type="text" maxlength="20" />`
5. **min & max**:
   `<input type="number" min="1" max="4" />`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, according to HTML5 drafts you can use the `pattern` attribute to specify the allowed input using a regular expression. For some types of data, you can use special input fields like `<input type=email>`. But these features still widely lack support or have qualitatively poor support.

Comment: Ah great! That's exactly the kind of thing I was hoping there might be. My google searches didn't turn up anything. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be very widely adopted yet.

Comment: @chaiguy, The `attr-input-pattern` from the [W3C Working Draft 29 March 2012](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-pattern) !

Comment: Unfortunately the spec only appears to define when an element is suffering from pattern mismatch, not how the browser should handle it. Ideally it would block the input from ever taking place, but it could just result in a red border or something silly like that.

Answer (score 5):

A little late, but a useful plugin that will actually use a mask to give a bit more restriction on user input.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="addPhone">Phone Number *</label>
      <input id="addPhone" name="addPhone" type="text" class="form-control 
       required" data-mask="(999) 999-9999"placeholder>
    <span class="help-block">(999) 999-9999</span>
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Input Mask -->
 <script src="js/plugins/jasny/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

More info on the plugin https://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/2.3.1/javascript.html#inputmask

Comment: This works well for data that is left aligned text. But if one wants a decimal number with only two decimal places after the comma, it does not fit.

Comment: @sergiol Did you try inputting what you wanted in the data-mask?

Answer (score -7):

Use this JavaScript.

```
$(":input").inputmask();
$("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"});
```