# How to prevent number input on keydown?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, keyboard-events

I want to prevent number input on *keydown event* on textfield and run custom handler function. Here are the issues

- `e.target.value` is useless since the key value is not projected into the target value yet
- `e.keyCode` for number depends on keyboard type, language layout, Fn or Shift key
- `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)` is not reliable, at least on my keyboard (Czech qwerty)
- [w3 specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#legacy-key-attributes) says `e.keyCode` is a legacy attribute and suggests `e.char` instead, but it is not implemented in browsers yet

So how to catch the number input before it appears in the textfield?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### 2024 answer

You could use the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property of the `keydown` event:

```js
document.getElementById("i").addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
  if (/^\d$/.test(evt.key)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="i">
```

### Original answer

Use the `keypress` event instead. It's the only key event which will give you information about the character that was typed, via the `which` property in most browsers and (confusingly) the `keyCode` property in IE. Using that, you can conditionally suppress the `keypress` event based on the character typed. However, this will not help you prevent the user from pasting or dragging in text containing numeric characters, so you will still need some kind of extra validation.

My favourite reference for JavaScript key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

```
textBox.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "undefined") ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (/\d/.test(charStr)) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Unbelievable! Sometimes is the `e.keyCode` different in `keypress` and `keydown` event! At least in my latest Chrome. Is it a feature or bug?

Comment: @JanTuroň: According to http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html, in WebKit `keyCode` is the same as `which` in `keypress` events, which could easily be different from the `keyCode` in a `keydown` event (think upper and lower case letters, for a start: same key code, different character codes).

Comment: @JanTuroň: Your edit was wrong, by the way, so I rolled it back. You only need to use `e.returnValue` in old IE, and even then not in DOM0 handlers like the one in my example.

Comment: The `keypress` event is depricated. MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Comment: @OOPSStudio: True. There are a number of old `keypress`-related answers of mine that I'm updating as and when I come across them.

Answer (score 16):

Try this to replace integer values:

```
<input onkeydown="Check(this);" onkeyup="Check(this);"/>

<script>
function Check(me) {
    me.value = me.value.replace(/[0-9]/g, "");
}
</script>
```

To prevent integer input:

```
<input onkeydown="Check(event);" onkeyup="Check(event);"/>

<script>
function Check(e) {
    var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Partially, see the second and third bullet in my question: number input on numeric part of keyboard ranges from 96 to 105, it doesn't return number on `String.fromCharCode` and it may also vary depending on keyboard layout and switching keys.

Answer (score 1):

## One-line solution

```
$('#input-field').keydown(e => !String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/\d/g))
```

Comment: I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` - is it some kind of obsolete library you suggest to use for such a simple task?

Comment: `$` coming from the jQuery library. I think almost everyone uses it :)

Comment: It was true in 2010, but [not anymore](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=should+i+use+jquery).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to prevent floating code characters

```
    // 'left arrow', 'up arrow', 'right arrow', 'down arrow',
    const = arrowsKeyCodes: [37, 38, 39, 40],
    // 'numpad 0', 'numpad 1',  'numpad 2', 'numpad 3', 'numpad 4', 'numpad 5', 'numpad 6', 'numpad 7', 'numpad 8', 'numpad 9'
    const = numPadNumberKeyCodes: [96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105],

    export const preventFloatingPointNumber = e => {
    // allow only [0-9] number, numpad number, arrow,  BackSpace, Tab
    if ((e.keyCode < 48 && !arrowsKeyCodes.includes(e.keyCode) || e.keyCode > 57 &&
        !numPadNumberKeyCodes.includes(e.keyCode)) &&
        !(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 9))
        e.preventDefault()
    }
```