# Why does my preventDefault not work in Chrome browser jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Look at my code, if you used chrome, you will notice that the preventDefault doesn't work when I press the Enter Key, but works in firefox and safari, why?

```js
var fighting_textarea=$('#fighting');
   
   fighting_textarea.on( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
     alert('hello');
    }
    
   });//click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="fighting"> </textarea>
```

Comment: In my machine it's working correctly, Update the browser and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine, you just have to remove alert(i guess it is not required). 
One more thing you should also consider code 10 too, b'coz on iphone safari gives code 10.

```js
var fighting_textarea=$('#fighting');
   
   fighting_textarea.on( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
     
    }
    
   });//click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="fighting"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `keypress` instead of `keydown`

```
var fighting_textarea = $('#fighting');
fighting_textarea.on("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hello');
    }

}); //click
```

Also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728261/how-to-prevent-number-input-on-keydown)

Also just noticed that if you remove the alert everything seems to be ok, as to why unfortunetly i have no idea.