# How can I prevent numeric inputs using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to create a validation that prevent the user from inputting numeric inputs on a textbox. I found some solution using a native javascript but it is not working on my side.

On my text box I have this trigger

```
v-on:keyup="preventNumericInput($event)">
```

And on my Vue I created a function on my class

```
preventNumericInput($event) {
    console.log($event.keyCode); //will display the keyCode value
    console.log($event.key); //will show the key value

    var keyCode = ($event.keyCode ? $event.keyCode : $event.which);
    if (keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) {
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728261/how-to-prevent-number-input-on-keydown

Comment: You should really be watching the input and reacting to numeric input. Alternatively you could use oninput

Comment: `keyup` might be too late an event to catch. Try `keydown` or `keypress`

Comment: Why don't use the [vee-validate](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate) ?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in my comment, `keyup` will be firing too late to prevent the value being entered into the input field. For example, think about holding a key down to enter the same value repeatedly; there is no key *up*.

Instead, use`keydown` or `keypress`

```
<input @keypress="preventNumericInput">
```

Demo ~ http://jsfiddle.net/wadt08jm/1/

Answer (score 0):

- Input must be type number, otherwise isNaN won't work

  ```
     <input type="number" :value="price" step="0.1" min="0" @input="onInput($event)" >
  ```
- into input replace ',' by '.'
- test if not number
- if not number replace observable price by element.value

```js
  data () {
    return { price: 0 }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput (e: Event) {
      const element = e.target as HTMLInputElement
      const value = parseFloat(element.value === '' ? '0' : element.value.replace(',', '.'))
      if (isNaN(value)) {
        element.value = this.price.toString()
      } else {
        this.price = value
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3, you can turn off the scroll to change when input type is number feature by modifying the input element's behavior using a directive. Here is the directive:

```
beforeMount(el, binding, vnode, prevVnode) {
  el.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
    if (el.type === 'nunmber') {
        el.blur()
        event.preventDefault()
      }
    },
    { passive: false }
)},
unmounted(el, binding, vnode, prevVnode) {
 document.body.removeEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
   el.blur()
   event.preventDefault()
 })
}
```