# Prevent entering numeric and Special Characters for input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

I have written a method that captures the entered key through event.

```
NameValidation(e){

    if(!e.key.match(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/))
    {
        e.key = '';
        console.log(e.key);
    }
},
```

What this does is basically checks if a user has entered a special character or number and if so
replaces the special character/number to an empty string.

The issue starts with `e.key = '';`.

As it does not replace the captured key. What am I missing here ?

Comment: You could use the [HTML pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) instead. <input type=“text” pattern=“[a-zA-Z]” />

Comment: @JordanStubblefield thanks for the feedback Jordan, i kind of wanted to do this in Vue js. Am new to vue and I wasn't sure how to implement it initially

Comment: Ah, no worries! Please mention those kind of details or at least put a vuejs tag next time ;)

Comment: @JordanStubblefield sure thank you for the help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized i was using Keypress event which was delayed in processing the trigger

So instead i used keydown and then used preventDefault to manipulate default event behaviour

This article Helped me
[How can I prevent numeric inputs using VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828016/how-can-i-prevent-numeric-inputs-using-vuejs)

**Here my Answer**

**JS**

```
      NameValidation(e){

            if(!e.key.match(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/))
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
           
        },
```

**Html**

```
<input v-model.trim="firstname_txt" v-on:keydown="NameValidation($event)">
```

Comment: a quick info: you can replace `v-on:` with `:` this is the short form: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand

Comment: @wittgenstein thank you for your guidance.. really appreciate it :)