# How to restrict decimal numbers in input="text" show only integer numbers

Tags: javascript, html

How to restrict decimal numbers from a `<input="text">`show only integer numbers. The field is only show like **11** not **11.00**

```
<input type="text">
```

Without using

```
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Use Math.round() on change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the decimal part from JavaScript number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641818/how-can-i-remove-the-decimal-part-from-javascript-number)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to mask characters in HTML(5) text input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887645/easiest-way-to-mask-characters-in-html5-text-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match()` method to checking format of input value.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("number");
var lastValue = "";

input.addEventListener("keydown", valueCheck);
input.addEventListener("keyup", valueCheck);

function valueCheck(){
    if (input.value.match(/^[0-9]*$/))
        lastValue = input.value; 
    else
        input.value = lastValue;
}
```

```html
<label>Type your value</label>
<input type="text" id="number" />
```

Comment: @J.Doe Is it your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt()` to remove decimal part **without rounding** (`11.9` => `11`, `11.1` => `11` and etc):

```
<input type="text" id="num">

var n = 11.13;
document.getElementById('num').value = parseInt(n); // 11
```

or just `+` operator:

```
var n = 11.13;
document.getElementById('num').value = +n; // 11
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can add a min attribute to your input html element.
like this

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" pattern="([d]+)">
```

You can use modern HTML5 attribute [pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) for input validation on client side. Input with decimal value would be invalid.

https://jsfiddle.net/rry32tm1/